# Spring security OpenID flow using JWT for authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, openid, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to do authentication for my web application using widely used [OpenId Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) flow.

I understand that the user who wants to authenticate on **example1.com** will first be redirected to the **authentication server** (or `OP` : "OpenId Provider"). The user authenticates on that server which then redirects him back to the original **example1.com** site with a signed JWT token.

**Technical challenges:**

I am suing **spring security** as part of my web application. I took a custom filter to redirect the user to **authentication server** and then it redirects back to my **example1.com** with valid `JWT (Json Web Token)`.

**My Custom Filter:**

```
public class MyCustomFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
   @Override

     public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
         //reading the AWT access token from reqest beahder
         String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");

         if(token == null){
            // redirecting user to authentication server
            String accessCodeUrl = "authentication.com?query string"
            response.sendRedirect(accessCodeUrl);
         } else{
            response.addHeader("Authorization", token);
         }
         //Now how can i inject the above received token to spring security
    }
}
```

**My spring xml config:**

```
<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="entryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <!-- set disabled to true to remove Cross Site Request Forger support -->
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="${MyCustomFilter }" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="${security.accessDeniedPage}"/>
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    </security:headers>        
</security:http>
```

My custom filter is extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. is it good fit for my requirement or should i consider extending any other filter's like `BasicAuthenticationFilter` or `OncePerRequestFilter` or `GenericFilterBean`.

I am confused here as to take 1 or 2 filters. because first time i am redirecting to **authorization server**, but from second time i should use the `JWT token` provided by **authentication server**.

Since i am going with `stateless` approach. I need to exchange `JWT token` every time between **example.com** and **browser**. I am using `ExtJs` as front end, what is the best practice to exchange `JWT token` between **browser** and **example.com**.

As per my understanding i should send `JWT token` every time from **browser** along with every request. Does that mean should i manually inject every time `JWT token` as part of `Ajax request` or Do we have some approach to append to all the outgoing `Ajax requests`.